# Asp.Net autoComplete Extender after populating values pressing down arrow not navigating through populated values

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I am using AjaxAutoComplete Extender to populate values of cities on the go.But i have a problem in it.

Everything works fine,But when i press the down arrow to navigate through the results,it does nothing,Its never moving from the first result..What am i doing wrong here..

And also values are populated on the top the webpage,not below the textbox..Earlier it was working fine,but not now..

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="fromlocation" runat="server" CssClass="ddl"></asp:TextBox>
<autofill:AutoCompleteExtender 
      ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
      ID="fromlocation_AutoCompleteExtender"
      runat="server"
      DelimiterCharacters=""
      Enabled="True"
      ServicePath="" 
      TargetControlID="fromlocation"
      UseContextKey="True"
      MinimumPrefixLength="2"
      CompletionInterval="10"
      EnableCaching="true"
      CompletionSetCount="3" 
      CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem">
</autofill:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**C#**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  coalesce(Code + ', ', '') + City as codes FROM CCode WHERE City LIKE '" + prefixText + "%'", conn);
            SqlDataReader oReader;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> CompletionSet = new List<string>();
            oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (oReader.Read())
                CompletionSet.Add(oReader["codes"].ToString());
            return CompletionSet.ToArray();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the above is listed in another forum..I found that by googling..

[AutoCompleteExtender Error](http://forums.asp.net/t/1480250.aspx?AutoCompleteExtender%20Error%20On%20Adding%20CompletionListItemCssClass)

IN the above code i added only

```
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
```

But in that forum thay have mentioned to define the below code as well..

```
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="two"
```

I did that and now my problem is solved..